# Sharing memory between user space and kernel space

Tags: winapi, memory, kernel

I am trying to share memory between user space and kernel space in windows xp.I want to write into the memory in user level and reading it from the kernel driver program.Is there any available in-build function?

Answer (score 6):

**User mode side:** There are a couple of ways.

1) The most common / flexible way is to use [`DeviceIOControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to communicate between user mode and kernel mode, including passing memory.

It's been a long time (six years?  XP timeframe) since I wrote my last kernel driver, so this is an overview of the process not exact code.  However, your user mode program should be able to obtain a handle to your 'device' or an open instance of your driver working on something by using `CreateFile` and specifying its name, such as `\\.\YourNameHere` for example.  Use that handle to communicate with it (the first parameter to `DeviceIOControl`.)

The four parameters you will be interested in are:

```
  __in_opt     LPVOID lpInBuffer,
  __in         DWORD nInBufferSize,
  __out_opt    LPVOID lpOutBuffer,
  __in         DWORD nOutBufferSize,
  __out_opt    LPDWORD lpBytesReturned,
```

Using these, you can give data to the driver (through the `lpInBuffer` pointer and `nInBufferSize`  parameter specifying how big it is - what this data is or how to interpret it is up to your driver) and the kernel-mode layer can give data back through `lpOutBuffer` (a pointer to memory you, in user mode, have already allocated - this is not a pointer that the driver sets!), its size in bytes in `nOutBufferSize` (again you know this, since you in user mode allocate this buffer) and then the driver will tell you how much of that buffer it actually filled with `lpBytesReturned`.

This Wikipedia article describes the [general concept of ioctl functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl), of which DeviceIOControl is an example.

**Note:** You said *"I am trying to share memory between user space and kernel space in windows"*.  This is not *exactly* shared memory - it's not memory that both user mode and kernel mode are reading from or writing to at the same time, for example.  It is memory where, for the duration of the `DeviceIOControl` function call, kernel mode has access to your user mode-allocated memory for which you pass it pointers (although from memory it's slightly more complicated than that, but that's the effect.)  Ie it's only 'shared' while you call that method.

2) Another alternative is to use [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you only need simple data transfer and the kernel driver accepts it.  It doesn't allow you to have two-way communication quite as `DeviceIOControl` does (where you give the driver data and it gives you something back with an error code) but it's simple and you're probably already familiar with those APIs.

**Kernel mode side:** Are you writing the kernel driver as well?  If so, [this article has information about implementing the kernel-mode side of IOCTL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9575/Driver-Development-Part-2-Introduction-to-Implemen).  This article series also describes allowing user mode to use `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` to communicate if you choose that methods.

Comment: The book [Rootkits: Subverting the Windows Kernel](http://www.amazon.com/Rootkits-Subverting-Windows-Greg-Hoglund/dp/0321294319) covers communicating with a Kernel driver via IRPs/DeviceIOControl in the first several chapters (at least, that's how far I've gotten in it so far.)